# Upload to YouTube and getting uploaded URL in excel

Tags: youtube

I have a list of 50 videos. 
Uploading the videos to YouTube. 
After uploading I will need to have the URL that the video is on in an excel spreadsheet. 
Doesn't want to do it manually..
Any auto way doing it? Using YouTube API? Or without?